# Case-insensitive str_replace

Tags: php

How do I use `str_replace` but to be case-insensitive when it searches for the string?

For example, suppose i want to replace `ABcD` with `a`. The resulting command would be `$string=str_replace("ABcD","a",$string);`. But if there is some string like "abCD" then again I have to use `$string=str_replace("abCD","a",$string);`.

Comment: If you look in the manual for str_replace (and on any functions page in the manual) there is a section that says "See Also". [Here is that section for str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace#refsect1-function.str-replace-seealso). Have a look at the first function it says to check out. Also, read the "Notes" section.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Then instead of using `str_replace` try using`str_ireplace` 
Its a case insensitive version of `str_replace` so use it as

```
$string = str_ireplace("ABcD","a",$string);
```

Comment: `$string=str_ireplace("ABcD","a",$string);`
Will this be the code ?